# number of thumbs-up and thumbs-down from rating

Tags: php, math

How to discover the number of thumbs-up and thumbs-down from the number of votes and the rating.

for example i have the `rating of +203` and `301 votes`. each vote is either -1 or +1

what i've tried

```
    $NEGATIVE_VOTES = ( $row['rating'] - $row['vote_num'] );
    $POSITIVE_VOTES = ( $row['vote_num'] - $NEGATIVE_VOTES );
```

Comment: maybe $row['vote_num'] - $row['rating']? vote_num >= 'rating'

Comment: So, a 'thumbs up' assigns a value of +1, and a 'thumbs down' a value of -1?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more about arithmetics than programming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
| rating | votes | positive | negative |
| 300    | 300   | 300      | 0        |
| 299    | 301   | 300      | 1        |
| 298    | 302   | 300      | 2        |
                ...
```

I hope you see the pattern. The number of negative votes is the difference between the rating and the number of votes **divided by 2**.

Answer (score 1):

So we have:

nb vote = 301
nb thumbup = x, nb thumbdown = y

we have x + y = 301 and x - y = 203

so 2y = 98 -> y = 49 -> x = total - y = 301 - 49 = 252

--> Nb thumb up = 252 and nb thumb down = 49